# Require confirmation to delete unread message? (Outlook 2013)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, inbox, unread-mail

Is there a configuration option in Outlook 2013 that will make the program prompt me for confirmation when I delete an *unread* email from my Inbox, but not when I delete an email that has already been read?  Looking in Settings and on Google, I haven't found anything.

Comment: There are no built-in methods for this. Closest call is for a macro

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like thanks!  If you know of such a macro, would you add it as an answer?  If not, I'll put it on my never-shrinking to-be-coded list... :|

Comment: I don't have any at hand right now. It shouldn't be impossible to write one but i am not an avid user of outlook too.